# Seo Website Authority - Difference between having HTTPS and not having it (Moz.com)

Tags: seo

So, I don't know much about SEO, but my boss came up with this website: https://moz.com/researchtools/ose/

I know that the Page Authority is a score calculated by this website only. We notice that if we use our full website url - https://www.example.com/ - the Page Authority is 1/100. But if we use - example.com - our page authority is 21/100.

Does anyone knows why does this happen?

Comment: FWIW DA / PA has nothing to do with Google SEO, it's just something Moz does. Moz folks are pretty smart cookies, and I'm sure there are good uses of the numbers, but they don't get used by Google at all. So if the number is confusing to you, don't worry that it has an effect on your rankings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take into account that Moz <strike>seo</strike> website authority score is determined according to a number of different metrics they have put together. In other words, the score represents their (and only theirs) overall evaluation and it has nothing to do with your website Google rankings.

Why this is happening? Several possible reasons: Moz only knows and have only weighted your HTTP website metrics, they have no computed or calculated your HTTPS version. Your HTTPS website version could be blocking Moz bots or they have problems crawling your website.

There are more reasons why this could be happening, but in general you should not be worry at all, this is an evaluation made by this folks only.

Comment: @DanielAlmeida it is good for the community to select the awnser you think was best...cheers.

Comment: Both answers helped me out tho :p But I did.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that at some point in time you were either using the non-www version as your main one, or didn't have a proper redirect in place to the www version?

That could cause the non-www version to still have specific incoming links that are then counted separately. In cases like these you should probably be looking at the DA (domain authority) to get a better picture of the website as a whole, instead of just using the PA, which only looks at the homepage in this case.

Comment: Thanks alot, the DA is 7/100 atm.
Yeah, at some point in time that happened, it was before we had the website with https.
So that means that with time, the https will have more PA?

Comment: Not necessarily will the https version ever have more PA, but assuming you keep at it with link building it most likely will.